# React Native Expo AuthSession; Google Authentication

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-platform, expo

I’m trying to setup the Google authentication using AuthSession in Expo documentation (without Firebase)
https://docs.expo.dev/guides/authentication/#google

The first problem is, that the slack example doesn’t work: on the devices and simulators nothing happen after pushing the button, and in web mode it returns an error

> Error 401: invalid_client
>
> The OAuth client was not found.

What I’ve done using steps in documentation:

- I’m not sure if it’s necessary, but I’ve installed `yarn add expo-application`
- I’ve registered in Credentials page ([Google Cloud Platform](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials))
- Logged in using `expo login`, in the terminal where I was starting `expo start`
- Created a new Google Client ID that will be used with `expoClientId`

[(Image) New Google Client ID setting image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSMED.png)

( I'm not allowed to input images now )

(Don’t know if it’s necessary) I’ve created a project in https://expo.dev/ and then published the project using dashboard of `expo start`

[(Image) Setting for "publish" in expo start dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWjFd.png)

Where:

```
“expo”: {
  “name”: “rn-my-project”,
  “slug”: “rn-my-project”,
  “version”: “1.0.0”,
  “orientation”: “portrait”,
  … 
}
```

Using the code in the example, provided in documentation for Google, I receive `null` as response.

As I understand, this should be enough to test the Google Authentication using AuthSession in Expo Go app. I also made `iosClientId`, `androidClientId` and `webClientId`, but I’m not sure if I made everything correct.

Will be glad for any help, because I couldn’t find any person with the problem as mine.

Yours sincerely.

P.S. I've successfully set up `logInAsync` for Google using this [documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v42.0.0/sdk/google/), but it's written, that it is deprecated.

Comment: Do you find any solution on this